# How to print the 'nth + x' lines after a match is found?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file which contains the output below. I want only the lines which contain the actual vm_id number.

I want to match pattern 'vm_id' and print 2nd line + all other lines until 'rows' is reached.

```
FILE BEGIN:
                vm_id                 
--------------------------------------
 bf6c4f90-2e71-4253-a7f6-dbe5d666d3a4
 bf6c4f90-2e71-4253-a7f6-dbe5d666d3a4
 6ffac9a9-1b6b-4600-8114-1ca0666951be
 47b5e6d1-6ddd-424a-ab08-18ee35b54ebf
 cc0e8b36-eba3-4846-af08-67ab72d911fc
 1b8c2766-92b7-477a-bc92-797a8cb74271
 c37bf1d8-a6b2-4099-9d98-179b4e573c64
(6 rows)

datacenter=
FILE END:
```

So the resulting output would be;

```
 bf6c4f90-2e71-4253-a7f6-dbe5d666d3a4
 6ffac9a9-1b6b-4600-8114-1ca0666951be
 47b5e6d1-6ddd-424a-ab08-18ee35b54ebf
 cc0e8b36-eba3-4846-af08-67ab72d911fc
 1b8c2766-92b7-477a-bc92-797a8cb74271
 c37bf1d8-a6b2-4099-9d98-179b4e573c64
```

Also, the number of VM Id's will vary, this example has 6 while others could have 3 or 300.

I have tried the following but they only output a single line that's specified;

```
awk 'c&&!--c;/vm_id/{c=2}' 
and
awk 'c&&!--c;/vm_id/{c=2+1}'
```

Comment: You have 7 rows in the input file.

Comment: removing `!` in the condition will print the following c rows including the all dashes row.

Comment: Yes, that was a bad copy of output. Sorry. There should have only been 1 bf6c4f90-2e71-4253-a7f6-dbe5d666d3a4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '/rows/{f=0} f&&(++c>2); /vm_id/{f=1}' file
 bf6c4f90-2e71-4253-a7f6-dbe5d666d3a4
 6ffac9a9-1b6b-4600-8114-1ca0666951be
 47b5e6d1-6ddd-424a-ab08-18ee35b54ebf
 cc0e8b36-eba3-4846-af08-67ab72d911fc
 1b8c2766-92b7-477a-bc92-797a8cb74271
 c37bf1d8-a6b2-4099-9d98-179b4e573c64
```

If you wanted that first line of hex(?) printed too then just change the starting number to compare c to from 2 to 1 (or 3 or 127 or however many lines you want to skip after hitting the vm_id line):

```
$ awk '/rows/{f=0} f&&(++c>1); /vm_id/{f=1}' file
 bf6c4f90-2e71-4253-a7f6-dbe5d666d3a4
 bf6c4f90-2e71-4253-a7f6-dbe5d666d3a4
 6ffac9a9-1b6b-4600-8114-1ca0666951be
 47b5e6d1-6ddd-424a-ab08-18ee35b54ebf
 cc0e8b36-eba3-4846-af08-67ab72d911fc
 1b8c2766-92b7-477a-bc92-797a8cb74271
 c37bf1d8-a6b2-4099-9d98-179b4e573c64
```

Comment: You are missing one line ;)

Comment: The OP did not clearly stated that he wants to dedup the first and the second id, but I now realized the difference between his input and desired output. Not sure if that's just a typo.... Anyway, your answer looks very nice and it's obviously not a problem to change it if desired..

Comment: This example works perfectly. awk '/rows/{f=0} f&&(++c>2); /vm_id/{f=1}' <file> I can use it against any vm_id length and I get the desired VM ID count as output. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
awk '/vm_id/{p=1;getline;next}/\([0-9]+ rows/{p=0}p'
```

I'm setting the `p` flag on `vm_id` and resetting it on `(0-9+ rows)`.

Also `sed` comes in mind, the command follows basically the same logic as the `awk` command above:

```
sed -n '/vm_id/{n;:a;n;/([0-9]* rows)/!{p;ba}}'
```

---

Another thing, if it is safe that the only [GUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) in your input file are the vm ids, `grep` might be the tool of choise:

```
grep -Eo '([0-9a-f]+-){4}([0-9a-f]+)'
```

It's not 100% bullet proof in this form, but it should be good enough for the most use cases.

Bullet proof would be:

```
grep -Eoi '[0-9a-f]{8}(-[0-9a-f]{4}){3}-[0-9a-f]{12}'
```